# Получение расстояние и времени до ближайшего метро

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, координаты

Хочу сделать подсчет ближайшего метро (кол-во задается) от определенной координаты. За основу взял вот этот пример:
https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/multiroute_data_access/

1. Добавил получение ближайшего метро
2. Прокладка пешего маршрута от исходной координаты.

Мой скрипт находит метро, прокладывает к ним маршруты, но я не могу вывести расстояние и необходимое время для каждого маршрута. Скрипт только выводит последний несколько раз. Вот все выложил на Fiddle

```
https://jsfiddle.net/Selection/5gbk0sgh/9/
```

Мне кажется тут основная проблема

```
ymaps.modules.require([
                'MultiRouteCustomView'
            ], function (MultiRouteCustomView) {
            // Создаем экземпляр текстового отображения модели мультимаршрута.
                new MultiRouteCustomView(multiRouteModel, metroName + " " + branch);
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант, который сработал для меня, ниже.

Обратите внимание, что при таком решении придется делать много запросов к маршрутизатору и, с учетом [запрета на сохранение ответов API](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/terms/index-docpage/?from=SO#conditions), есть риск превысить [дневной лимит](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/terms/index-docpage/?from=SO#limits).

```js
ymaps.ready(init);

function init() {
  var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
    center: [55.753994, 37.622093],
    zoom: 9
  }, {
    searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
  });
  myGeoObject = new ymaps.GeoObject({
    geometry: {
      type: "Point",
      coordinates: myMap.getCenter()
    },
    // Свойства.
    properties: {
      iconContent: 'Перетащи и я определю ближайшие метро'
    }
  }, {
    preset: 'islands#blackStretchyIcon',
    draggable: true
  });
  myMap.geoObjects.add(myGeoObject);

  myGeoObject.events.add("dragend", function() {
    //если метку подвинули, ищем 3 ближайших станций метро
    ymaps.geocode(myGeoObject.geometry.getCoordinates(), {
      kind: 'metro',
      results: 3
    }).then(function(res) {
      
      myMap.geoObjects.removeAll();
      document.getElementById("viewContainer").innerHTML = "";
      myMap.geoObjects.add(myGeoObject);
      res.geoObjects.options.set('preset', 'islands#redCircleIcon');
      myMap.geoObjects.add(res.geoObjects);
      myMap.setBounds(myMap.geoObjects.getBounds());

      //а теперь построим до каждого маршрут
      for (let i = 0; i < res.geoObjects.getLength(); i++) {

        let multiRouteModel = new ymaps.multiRouter.MultiRouteModel([
            myGeoObject.geometry.getCoordinates(),
            res.geoObjects.get(i).geometry.getCoordinates()
          ], {
            routingMode: 'pedestrian'
          }),
          multiRoute = new ymaps.multiRouter.MultiRoute(multiRouteModel);
        myMap.geoObjects.add(multiRoute);
        multiRouteModel.events.add("requestsuccess", function() {
          var route = multiRouteModel.getRoutes()[0];
          document.getElementById("viewContainer").innerHTML += "до станции " + res.geoObjects.get(i).getPremise() + " " + route.properties.get("distance").text + " или " + route.properties.get("duration").text + " пешком" + "</br>";
        }) //конец модели        
      }
      //конец for 
    }); //конец .then


  }) //конец dragend

}
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 75%;
}

#viewContainer {
  margin: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="viewContainer"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему с помощью добавление синхронных (не ассинхронных) запросов

```
ymaps.ready(function () {
    yma ps.modules.require([
    'MultiRouteCustomView'
    ], init)
    });
    function init(MultiRouteCustomView) {
       ...
    }
```